# Can't generate ssh key on Windows 7

Tags: ssh, windows-7, cmd, ssh-keygen

I'm kind of new for the theme, so it might be a stupid question to ask, but I have no idea what to do.
The following command:

```
ssh keygen -t rsa
```

gives me the following result:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname keygen: no address associated with name
```

Operating system is Windows 7. Do I miss some package?

Comment: It's `ssh-keygen` (on Unix anyway)

Comment: *facepalm* thanks, that was it!

Comment: Please, add it as an answer to remove this question from unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was really stupid. I've forgotten dash in the middle. It has to be `ssh-keygen -t rsa`